# "ESC" Character in test.log when viewed in Sublime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Whenever I open up test.log from any rails application I get the following screenshot in Sublime. I've tried messing around with encodings, but couldn't find anything that fixed it.

[image]

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

Comment: Those are the character sequences that colorize the log output when watched in a Terminal.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of them? Is rails colorizing things or is it one of the gems I have installed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

These are control characters used to add colour to the log files. Sublime text apparently doesn't support this.

If you're mostly going to be viewing log files with editors that don't understand these colour codes you can turn this off with the rails `config.colorize_logging` setting

Comment: Just to be clear, this is a setting in ruby-on-rails, and not Sublime Text.

Comment: So that, if the question is in Sublime Text, why `config.colorize_logging`? this doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 10):

There's a Sublime package to turn these ANSI/vt100 escape sequences into colored text -- [SublimeANSI](https://github.com/aziz/SublimeANSI)
(use [Package Control and look for ANSIescape](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ANSIescape)) -- this adds an "ANSI" file type that will display your log file in glorious color.  (The file is displayed read-only but you can change the type back to "Plain Text" if you want to edit it.)

Comment: SublimeANSI FTW. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Backing up Tom Hundt's answer... SublimeANSI is the way to go. Compare these before/after shots:

**Sublime's default rendering of colorized Rails log output:**

[image: Sublime's default rendering of colorized Rails log output]

**Now change the syntax highlighting to `ANSI`:**

[image: Now change the syntax highlighting to ANSI]

**Now, marvel in the majesty of SumblimeANSI's rendering:**

[image]

Learn more about SublimeANSI package at: https://github.com/aziz/SublimeANSI

Note: To install it in Package Manager, search for "ANSIescape" ... NOT "SublimeANSI". This confused me for a hot minute.